# Session problem with general destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was migrating a system rail2 to rails3, and got a problem when I tried to delete a item from a list. I just clicked the delete link, then session was destroyed and item was not destroyed. That problem happened in all controllers and with all three session stores. I deleted gems except rails and mysql2 and tried it but result was same. I emptied destroy actions of session stores but that was happened too. Btw, if I didn't use session, the item was destroyed.

view:

```
    <%= link_to image_tag("icons/10.png" ,:size => "20x20", :alt => "show", :border => 0, :class => "show"), admin_info_path(info) -%>
    <%= link_to image_tag("icons/2.png" ,:size => "20x20", :alt => "edit", :border => 0, :class => "edit"), edit_admin_info_path(info) -%>
    <%= link_to image_tag("icons/9.png" ,:size => "20x20", :alt => "delete", :border => 0, :class => "delete"), admin_info_path(info), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6'
gem "settingslogic", "~> 2.0.6"
gem 'jpmobile', '0.1.6'
gem "kaminari"
gem "memcache-client"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost always a result of [request forgery protection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html). Make sure you have [`<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper.html) and a working `rails.js` or [`jquery_ujs.js`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) JavaScript include inside the `<head>` tag of your layout.

`<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` will usually include these files automatically.

If you're still having trouble, you can always comment out the `protect_from_forgery` call (probably inside your `application_controller.rb` file) just to see if that is what is causing your problem. But I wouldn't recommend turning off forgery protection permanently for security reasons.